# For loop without looping if statement

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Bok1.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb["Blad1"]

n = 0

for row in ws['A1:A100']:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Konto":
            for hej in range(13):
                n+=1
                konto = cell.offset(row=n).value
                if konto == None or isinstance(konto, str) == True:
                    pass
                else:
                     if konto == 306888 or konto == 306889:
                        #derp = input("derpderpderp?: ")
                        #if derp == "y":
                            if konto == 306888 or konto == 306889:
                                kst = cell.offset(row=n, column = 1).value
                                proj = cell.offset(row=n, column = 2).value
                                vht = cell.offset(row=n, column = 3).value
                                motp = cell.offset(row=n, column = 4).value
                                fin = cell.offset(row=n, column = 5).value
                                text = cell.offset(row=n, column = 8).value
                                belopp = cell.offset(row=n, column = 9).value
                                print(konto)
                                print(kst)
                                print(proj)
                                print(vht)
                                print(motp)
```

As you can see by the # in the code, I have a input that is "dependent" on a loop. How could I write this code so that it is not looping over and asking for the input for every iteration?

Comment: Why did you put it in the loop if you don't want it to happen in the loop?

Comment: I do not know where to put it. The outcome i want is that after iterating through 13 cells: if any cells contains 306888 or 306889: ask for input: if the input is "y": take the 7 values to the right of every 306888 or 306889 it encounters within those 13 cells.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to keep a counter:

```py
n = 0
cnt=1         # counter

for row in ws['A1:A100']:
       # continue with your code
```

Then, when you get to your input :

```py
if cnt==1:
   derp = input("derpderpderp?: ")
   cnt += 1
   if derp == "y":
      #continue with your code
```

This way, you ensure that your input is taken only on the first go.